# Maximum value change after filter criteria met

Tags: python, pandas

The following dataframe ([df.to_csv here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32282382/df_zzag)) is filtered based on `abs(ZZag_Line_Len > 6)`.

```
                  Rev_Price ZZag_Line_Len
Timestamp       
2015-09-01 09:46:01.600 1902.50 8.00
2015-09-01 09:59:46.000 1891.00 -6.25
2015-09-01 09:59:57.300 1899.00 8.00
2015-09-01 10:00:21.600 1891.50 -7.50
2015-09-01 10:17:11.400 1895.25 6.25
2015-09-01 10:23:27.600 1889.00 -6.25
2015-09-01 10:35:30.500 1902.25 8.25
```

I also have the unfiltered dataframe and I now want to see how far price goes for each `ZZag_Line_Len` with a cut off point being the end of each day (data is 9:30 -16:15).

```
                    Open    High    Low Last    ZZag    Rev_Price   ZZag_Line_Len   ZZag Mid-Point
Timestamp                               
2015-09-01 09:30:00.000 1887.75 1888.00 1887.75 1887.75 1887.75 0.00    0.00    0.00
2015-09-01 09:30:01.000 1888.25 1888.50 1888.25 1888.50 1888.25 0.00    0.00    1889.25
2015-09-01 09:30:01.200 1888.25 1889.00 1888.00 1889.00 1888.75 0.00    0.00    1889.25
2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 1889.25 1889.50 1889.25 1889.50 1889.25 0.00    0.00    1889.25
2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 1889.50 1890.00 1889.50 1890.00 1889.75 0.00    0.00    1889.25
2015-09-01 09:30:12.000 1890.00 1890.50 1889.75 1890.50 1890.25 0.00    0.00    1889.25
2015-09-01 09:30:15.300 1890.25 1890.75 1889.50 1889.50 1890.75 1890.75 3.00    1889.25
2015-09-01 09:30:30.500 1889.50 1890.00 1889.00 1889.00 1890.08 0.00    0.00    1888.75
2015-09-01 09:30:36.100 1889.00 1889.75 1888.50 1888.50 1889.42 0.00    0.00    1888.75
```

Here is a plot showing what I am looking for:

[image]

So if `ZZag_Line_Len` is 8.25 as per `2015-09-01 10:35:30.500` on the plot I want to see how much higher the `ZZag` or `High` value goes for that day before `ZZag` or `Low` moves under 1894 which was the base of the move. On the plot we see `ZZag` move under 1894 around 10:45 so  we would log the `max_move` and look at the next instance.

Sometimes there are moves lower and higher on the same day and ideally I would be able to see how far each move went before price went above/below the base of the move.

Desired output is a new column showing `max_move` for each `ZZag_Line_Len`.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to approach this or even help with the code please?

Column names edited and image uploaded as per request to clarify.

[image: dfimage]

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out data columns and headers. Can you perhaps edit your question such that column names start or end with the data in that column? At least put underscores between the words that make up one column, so that I will know where what belongs. For instance, I don't know if `ZZag Line Length` is one column or two.

Comment: Hi Kartik, I renamed the columns and have uploaded an image to keep columns aligned.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: So for each day, you want to know what the maximum and minimum High and Low values are? Or does `ZZag_Line_Length` have anything to do with what you want? I don't work with price data, and have little knowledge about what arithmetic goes behind making sense of the data. So you will need to explicitly specify what you are looking for. Sorry.

Comment: Also attached `df.to_csv` data in post

Comment: `ZZag_Line_Len` is showing a price move either up or down.  If the move is positive I want the high for the day in the 'max_move' column.  If the move is negative I want the low for the day. thanks

Comment: That's easy to do. However, in the first code block in your question, the one where you show the results of `abs(ZZag_Line_Length) > 6`, all data belongs to just one day. There are both +ve and -ve values for 2015-09-01, which means, you will get both High and Low values for `'max_move'` on that day. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry Kartik you are absolutely correct.  I was going to look at this as a separate question afterwards as I thought it may be too much to ask.  Each `ZZag_Line_Len` is a directional move and I am looking for the maximum distance price continues in this direction on the same day.  On some days there are opposing moves and ideally I would be able to see how far each move went before price went above/below the source of the move.

Comment: So for example.  On 2015-09-01 09:30:15 (see image above) there is a reversal price at 1890.75.  I would like to see how far price goes on the same day before it goes under 1890.75 again.  Same for all `ZZag_Line_Len`.

Comment: Do you want the global maxima and minima for each direction, or the local maxima and minima? And the base reference will be the open value of the given day, correct?

Comment: Im sorry but I don't understand what these values are (global maxima and minima/local maxima and minima).  If there is an option to have both that would be great and I will learn something new.  The start of the move is the reversal price so would this not be the base reference?  Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I guess you couldn't find it when you Googled the terms... Here is the Wikipedia article on [maxima and minima](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima).

Comment: I did google it but I don't understand it enough to talk with you about it.  I didn't want to pretend I understood.

Comment: I added a plot to help explain and tried to tidy up the post and clarify.

Comment: So you are after the global extrema. Compare the plot in your question with the one from the Wikipedia article on maxima and minima. You are not interested in the small ups and downs, you want what was the maximum and the minimum of all those ups and downs compared to the Open value for a day. Correct me if I'm wrong. If not, I'll post an answer in a few...

Comment: The global extreme sounds correct Kartik.  I'm not quite sure how the max move relates to the open though.  Perhaps you could show me if this is ok?